# Kannel: ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use

Tags: linux, mobile, sms, port, kannel

I cannot run kannel(an open source sms gateway) run properly. Everytime I try I get this error. ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use

Here is my kannel.conf

```
group = core
admin-port = 13000
admin-password = 123
status-password = 123
smsbox-port = 13003
wapbox-port = 13004
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_core.log"
log-level = 1
wdp-interface-name = "*"

#group = smsc
#smsc = fake
#port = 1000

group = smsbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
sendsms-port = 13013
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_smsbox.log"
log-level = 1

group = wapbox
bearerbox-host = 127.0.0.1
log-file = "/home/eclipse/kannel_wapbox.log"

group = sendsms-user
username = 123
password = 123
user-allow-ip = "127.0.0.1"

group = sms-service
url="http://localhost/sms/send.php?sender=%s&&text=%t"
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
```

and the log file for the core:

```
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/home/eclipse/kannel_core.log' with level `1'.
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13000.
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: bind failed
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: Adding interface *
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: Couldn't bind a UDP socket to port 9200
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: Couldn't bind a UDP socket to port 9201
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version 1.4.3 starting
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] ERROR: bind failed
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] ERROR: System error 98: Address already in use
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: Could not open wapbox port 13004
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: /usr/sbin/bearerbox(gw_panic+0xd2) [0x80d1b62]
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: /usr/sbin/bearerbox() [0x8055bc0]
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: /usr/sbin/bearerbox() [0x80c8bbb]
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d31) [0x7a5d31]
2012-02-23 21:26:36 [9194] [7] PANIC: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xbba0ce]
```

I have tried to do a lot of changes but none successful. Kindly let me know which point I am missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something else is running at ports 13000, 9200, 9201 and 13004 - most likely another instance of kannel.

do `sudo netstat -lanp` to see what process it is.

Comment: I can see localhost:13000 is waiting for close but I cannot find any process id. Which command/trick can I use to free the port in this case.

Comment: did you try running netstat as root?

Comment: yes. How can I free the localhost:13000. No much details is provided

Comment: Thank you so much for the ideas. I used lsof -i -p 9200 and lsof -i -p 13000 terminal commands to get the processes and killed them using kill -9 PID.All done when root. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop kannel service `/etc/init.d/kannel stop` and start it `/etc/init.d/kannel start` after few seconds.
I found out that sometime if you stop kannel service, it takes some few seconds to shutdown completely.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error occur without the kannel piece but the etc/hosts file had a bad host/ip configured and the DNS at the site was pointing to the wrong server so Oracle listener could not be reached.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment (but maybe you do not have enough rep to comment?)